# What is the CHARINDEX (SQL SERVER) equivalent in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, charindex

I am trying `CHARINDEX` in Postgresql. But it says:

```
function CHARINDEX() does not exist
```

If no such inbuilt function exists in postgresql, then is there any function that serves as an alternative to charindex?

If yes, What is the `CHARINDEX` (SQL SERVER) equivalent in POSTGRESQL ?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html (probably you need `position(...)` )

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The equivalent function in postgresql is:

```
strpos(string, substring)
```

Or:

```
position(substring in string)
```

They are equivalent, just with different order in parameters.

If you also need parameter start_location, you will need to pass a substring to strpos.

You can find them in: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1):

- In SQL Server *CHARINDEX* syntax is

  ```
  SELECT CHARINDEX(Substring, String)
  ```

  and example as like

  ```
  SELECT CHARINDEX('m','Zarm')
  ```

  this query returned `4`.
- Case of *PostgreSQL* syntax is

  ```
  strpos(string, substring)
  ```

  And example is

  ```
  SELECT strpos('Amal', 'l')
  ```

  this query returned `4`.