# Split string into words using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I am looking for some help in separating scientific names in my data. I want to take only the genus names and group them, but they are both connected in the same column. I saw the SQL Sever had a CHARINDEX command, but PostgreSQL does not. Does there need to be a function created for this? If so, how would it look?

I want to change `'Mallotus philippensis'` to just `'Mallotus'` or to just `'philippensis'`

I am currently using Postgres 11, 12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the CHARINDEX (SQL SERVER) equivalent in POSTGRESQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778444/what-is-the-charindex-sql-server-equivalent-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

Probably `string_to_array` will be slightly more efficient than `split_part` here because string splitting will be done only once for each row.

```
SELECT
  val_arr[1] AS genus,
  val_arr[2] AS species
FROM (
  SELECT string_to_array(val, ' ') as val_arr
  FROM (
    VALUES
      ('aaa bbb'),
      ('cc dddd'),
      ('e fffff')
  ) t (val)
) tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPLIT_PART`:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Mallotus philippensis'::text AS genus
)

SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(genus, ' ', 1) AS genus,
    SPLIT_PART(genus, ' ', 2) AS species
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo