# SQL's CHARINDEX Syntax exception

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, substring

I am trying to select numeric part of string and find a maximum from it. I write this code, but something goes wrong, when i added CHARINDEX function.

```
  Integer sss= (Integer) em.createQuery("SELECT max(cast(SUBSTRING(s.fam, 1, CHARINDEX('-',s.fam)-1) as integer)) FROM Teacher s").getSingleResult();
```

**It gives me:**

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   extract ResultSet
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Syntax error
>   (approximately position: "as")

I got the same with PATINDEX and LOCATE functions.

Comment: `SELECT max(cast(SUBSTRING(s.fam, 1, CHARINDEX('-',s.fam)-1))) as integer FROM Teacher s`

Comment: I think you have a problem with parenthesis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778444/what-is-the-charindex-sql-server-equivalent-in-postgresql/30780989

Comment: Your error points to PostgreSQL - does it have the function you are using?

Comment: "SQL" has no function `charindex()` and neither does PostgreSQL. All supported functions are listed here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: With position() and strpos() i got the same issues

Comment: @YCF_L it doens't helped

Answer (score 1):

Well **STRPOS** works just fine in Postgres 12 (fiddle): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=23ab8f41f29775f056717fc6af8c2b71

You need to replace `charindex()` with `strpos()`

All this is in the comments, I know, but maybe you had a problem with the fact that STRPOS parameters are like this:

```
strpos(string, substring)
```

[STRPOS DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de4fd1812fe58b690501118db0c5326a)

And for CHARINDEX are like this:

```
CHARINDEX(substring, string)
```

[CHARINDEX DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af718f490fece3f5e6e666a209fc1b3e)

In your line of code you also have to be careful with :

> ERROR:  negative substring length not allowed
>   This will hapend when there is no '-' in the string

[Here is example for that.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a90e0db151bc0f311251376f5b6f615e)

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "test"

[Here is example for that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f4615d5bcc16ff1cedc0ab5a2d8898a0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with this

Comment: Integer sss= (Integer) em.createQuery("SELECT max(cast(SUBSTRING(s.fam, 1, strpos(s.fam, '-')-1) as integer)) FROM Teacher s").getSingleResult(); i got the same error

Comment: @Vytsalo have you checked  the possible problems I have warned about ? HAve you checked the data in s.fam column ?

Comment: yes, it have only 2 records  with fields "123-aks" and "348-cbs"

Comment: Ok, so, two questions : 1. with my code and this data you get the same error like in your question ? 2. Is this the text for the error in your question the whole text ? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Vytsalo Please can you answer to my questions here in comments. Thanks!